# PnP Poweshell: Get-PnPListItem Restrict to a Specific View

Tags: list, powershell, list-view, pnp-powershell

I'm using `Get-PnpList` and `Get-PnpListItem` to retrieve all items in a specific list, but I would like to restrict the items to only those in a specific view?

Is this possible? Maybe with a CAML query, etc..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Unfortunately**, There is no direct parameter like `-View` to specify your `View Name` in **`Get-PnPListItem`**

**Meanwhile,** as a workaround solution, you can pass the **`CAML Query`** to the **`-Query`** parameter based on your **`View setting`**.

**Ex:**

```
Get-PnPListItem -List Tasks -Query "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='GUID'/><Value Type='Title'>Qassas</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>
```

> Note: you can build your CAML Query by using [U2U tool](https://www.u2u.be/software)