# Can the code from Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell be translated to PnPPowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I would like to translate the code below that is made with the commands from module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell to PnpPowerShell. Is that possible?

```
#Get the Target List
$list = $web.Lists["MyList"]
#Get the View
$view = $list.Views["ToPrint"] 

#Get All items from the view
$items = $list.GetItems($view)
```

Gr, P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PnP Poweshell: Get-PnPListItem Restrict to a Specific View](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/247543/pnp-poweshell-get-pnplistitem-restrict-to-a-specific-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, pnp does not support querying a list based on a view, though it does support using a caml query.